# Play Framework 2.1 and Ebean: model Finder returns no data

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

I've been banging my head around this for hours. I have two models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class AppUser extends Model {

    @Id
    Long id;

    …

    @Constraints.Required
    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    public LocationAddress address;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
    public LocationAddress addressBilling;

    …

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "location_address")
public class LocationAddress extends Model {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MaxLength(TextSize.DEFAULT)
    @Column(length = TextSize.DEFAULT, nullable = false)
    public String street;

    @Constraints.MaxLength(TextSize.TINY)
    @Column(length = TextSize.TINY)
    public String streetNo;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = false)
    public Country country;

    …

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    public AppUser userAddress;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "addressBilling")
    public AppUser userAddressBilling;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    public AdvertisingLocation advertisingLocationAddress;

    // -- Queries

    public static Finder<Long, LocationAddress> find = new Finder<Long, LocationAddress>(Long.class, LocationAddress.class);

    public static List<LocationAddress> all() {
        return find.all();
    }

    public static LocationAddress findById(long id) {
        return find.byId(id);
    }

}
```

The problem is that `LocationAddress.all()` returns nothing, and thus `AppUser.findById(1).address.street` throws `EntityNotFoundException: Bean has been deleted - lazy loading failed`. Needless to say, the database table is not empty.

Interestingly, `Ebean.find(LocationAddress.class).findRowCount()` returns 3 (this is correct).

Anyone seeing what could be the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many more hours I finally found the source of the problem. `@OneToOne` fields in `LocationAddress` are not needed and cause the entity not be returned if null.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. How did you resolve the problem? I see the same thing.

Comment: If it's a bidirectional relationship, then both sides of the relation must not be null for the objects to be returned, as the case was here. I changed it to a one-directional relationship, so objects are returned even if one side is null.

Comment: ah. you removed all `@OneToOne` fields from the class and then `find.all`worked. I understand that now. But seems to me more digging it required. In your case you didn't need them. Others might need them. Can you post your DB so I can reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a couple of times.  (play 1 as well. )

My way to resolve this is to make the field private and wrap it with getter/setter.